# Check if item exists and return matched elements using .Contains() on anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a **collection of dates** (possibly duplicates) that I need to check against using `.Contains()` or a similar method.

I create an anonymous type like this:

```
var bookedDates = (from b in db.Bookings
                    where b.BookingDate > DateTime.Today
                    select new
                    {
                        Date = b.BookingDate,
                        StatusID = b.StatusId
                    });
```

I then have a collection of dates `(d)`, and I need to test whether `d` exists within my anonymous type. This would be easy using a dictionary since I can use the `.ContainsKey()`.

If a date exists within the anonymous type, I need to get the one or multiple items that correspond to the date I'm testing.

Is there a quick way to do this, I know I can do it by looping and testing each and every key but looking for a faster/more efficient way.

In essence, I'm looking for a dictionary that supports duplicate items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to check whether you have the date already you can use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), then check the hashset in the following queries etc.:

```
HashSet<DateTime> dates = new HashSet<DateTime>();
foreach (var item in bookedDates)
    dates.Add(item.Date);

..
if (dates.Contains(someDate))
{
    //...
}
```

**Edit:**

I *think* you just want a lookup based on the items in your query:

```
var dateLookup = db.Bookings
                   .Where( b => b.BookingDate > DateTime.Today)
                   .ToLookup( p => p.BookingDate, 
                              p => p.StatusId);
```

A lookup allows a collection of items for each key, so that might be what you are looking for.

Then you can just use it like this:

```
var statusIdsForToday = dateLookup[DateTime.Now.Date].ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah but the point is to try not loop through each and every item but do a lookup instead, also I need the StatusID as part of the collection...

Comment: @Marko: so do you not need bookDates at all? You *just* want a dictionary?

Comment: ToLookup is exactly what I needed. Wasn't aware of this method. Cheers +1

Answer (score 0):

var distinctNames = bookedDates.Distinct();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm getting it wrong, but you can apply another LINQ query on your `bookedDates`, something like this:

```
DateTime searchDateTime = DateTime.Now; // or any other DateTime
var statusIds = (from b
                 in bookedDates
                 where b.Date == searchDateTime // or a similar comparison
                 select b.StatusID);
var statusIdsList = statusIds.ToList();
```

*edit:* if the search dates are from the same database then a *join* would be an option

```
var bookedIds = (from b
                 in db.Bookings
                 join dates in db.SearchDates on b.BookingDate equals dates
                 select b.StatusId);
```

(assuming that the dates to compare are located in `db.SearchDates`, if necessary, add a `where dates > DateTime.Now` or other restrictions on the dates)

Comment: I'm getting the search dates from a database and have about 60 dates to test so that would mean 60 round trips to the database..

Comment: I've edited my entry to add another possible code fragment using a join operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bookedDates = (from b in db.Bookings
        where b.BookingDate > DateTime.Today
        select new 
        {
            date = b.BookingDate,
            statusId = b.StatusId
        }).GroupBy(x => x.date).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

This should give you an IEnumerable of type IGrouping of type DateTime, StatusID type

Comment: You can do this without mixing syntaxes :)